# Decorator execution order

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

```
def make_bold(fn):
    return lambda : "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"

def make_italic(fn):
    return lambda : "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"

@make_bold
@make_italic
def hello():
  return "hello world"

helloHTML = hello()
```

Output: `"<b><i>hello world</i></b>"`

I roughly understand about decorators and how it works with one of it in most examples.

In this example, there are 2 of it. From the output, it seems that `@make_italic` executes first, then `@make_bold`.

Does this mean that for decorated functions, it will first run the function first then moving towards to the top for other decorators? Like `@make_italic` first then `@make_bold`, instead of the opposite.

So this means that it is different from the norm of top-down approach in most programming lang? Just for this case of decorator? Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes it starts from the bottom up passing the result to the next

Comment: @PadraicCunningham comment is as well an important portion of the answer. Had a related problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042196/why-are-my-python-mock-patches-appearing-in-the-wrong-order)

Comment: I'd say it's still top-down, in the sense that `a(b(x))` is top-down (if you imagine that split over 3 lines)

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Decorators *wrap* the function they are decorating. So `make_bold` decorated the result of the `make_italic` decorator, which decorated the `hello` function.

The `@decorator` syntax is really just syntactic sugar; the following:

```
@decorator
def decorated_function():
    # ...
```

is really executed as:

```
def decorated_function():
    # ...
decorated_function = decorator(decorated_function)
```

replacing the original `decorated_function` object with whatever `decorator()` returned.

Stacking decorators repeats that process *outward*.

So your sample:

```
@make_bold
@make_italic
def hello():
  return "hello world"
```

can be expanded to:

```
def hello():
  return "hello world"
hello = make_bold(make_italic(hello))
```

When you call `hello()` now, you are calling the object returned by `make_bold()`, really. `make_bold()` returned a `lambda` that calls the function `make_bold` wrapped, which is the return value of `make_italic()`, which is also a lambda that calls the original `hello()`. Expanding all these calls you get:

```
hello() = lambda : "<b>" + fn() + "</b>" #  where fn() ->
    lambda : "<i>" + fn() + "</i>" # where fn() -> 
        return "hello world"
```

so the output becomes:

```
"<b>" + ("<i>" + ("hello world") + "</i>") + "</b>"
```

Comment: I understand. But does this mean that when there are 2 wrappers in this case, the IDE will automatically detect and wrap the result of the first wrapper? Because I thought that             `@make_bold #make_bold = make_bold(hello)`
`@make_italic #make_italic = make_italic (hello)`? I'm not sure if based on this, it will wrap the first result. Or for this case of 2 wrappers, the IDE will use `make_bold(make_italic(hello))` as you have mentioned instead of what I shared?

Comment: @Newbie: Your IDE does nothing here; it is *Python* that does the wrapping. I showed you in my last sample that `make_bold()` wraps the output of `make_italic()`, which was used to wrap `hello`, so the equivalent of `make_bold(make_italic(hello))`.

Comment: Could you provide a version of this code without the use of lambda? I had tried .format but doesn't work. And why lambda is used in this example? I'm trying to understand lambda and how it works in this example but still having problems. I get that lambda is like one line functions that can be passed much easily as compared to the norm of def functions?

Comment: `def inner: return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"`, then `return inner` would be the 'regular' function version; not that big a difference.

Comment: I always get confused about order. ["...decorators will be applied starting with the one closest to the "def" statement"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#Order_of_Decorators)  I call this "inside-out". I think Martijn calls this "outward". This means `make_italic` **decorator** is executed before `make_bold` **decorator**, because `make_italic` is closest to the `def`. However, I forget that **decorated** code execution order: the `make_bold` **decorated** (i.e. bold lambda) is executed first, followed by the `make_italic` **decorated** lambda (i.e. italic lambda).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, can you please help me understand why the instance is passed as an argument via args when a regular method is decorated as a property but not when it is decorated by some other method ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar: I think you are looking for [my explanation of how `@property` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python/17330273#17330273).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you have explained this several times before to others but can you please confirm if my understanding is correct, args is non empty and contains an instance of the original calling object and this args belongs to the returned property() object ? In -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065914/decorating-with-property-results-in-additional-argument-being-passed the property() , can you please explain why the difference exists ? I am not able to find the answer in your explanation.

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar: I'm not certain what difference you are referring to. I _think_ what is confusing you is how _descriptors_ work. The `property()` object is a descriptor, and so are functions. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Answer (score 25):

I think the answer to this question seems straightforward but itsn't. When we talk about the decorator's order of execution I think we have to remember that the decorators themselves are evaluated at different moments during the execution: when the Python interpreter is evaluating the decorated method definition itself and when the decorated method is called/executed. The order of decorators as I could see in my experiments is different between these two phases.

Besides, keep in mind that when decorating a function we could have code that executes **before** the decorated method and code that runs **after**. This makes things even more complicated when nesting decorators.

So, in a few words:

- When the interpreter is evaluating the decorated method definition the decorators are evaluated from ***bottom --> top***
- When the interpreter calls the decorated method the decorators are called from ***top --> bottom***.

Consider the following code example:

```
print("========== Definition ==========")
def decorator(extra):
    print(" in decorator factory for %s " % extra)
    extra = " %s" % extra
    def inner(func):
        print(" defining decorator %s " % extra)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("before %s -- %s" % (func.__name__, extra))
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("after %s -- %s" % (func.__name__, extra))
        return wrapper
    return inner

@decorator('first')
@decorator('middle')
@decorator('last')
def hello():
    print('  Hello ')

print("\n========== Execution ==========")
hello()
```

The outtput of this code is the following:

```
========== Definition ==========
 in decorator factory for first 
 in decorator factory for middle 
 in decorator factory for last 
 defining decorator  last 
 defining decorator  middle 
 defining decorator  first 

========== Execution ==========
before wrapper --  first
before wrapper --  middle
before hello --  last
  Hello 
after hello --  last
after wrapper --  middle
after wrapper --  first
```

As we can see in this output the order is different (as explained before). During the definition, decorators are evaluated from bottom to top meanwhile during the execution (which is the most important part in general) they are evaluated from top to bottom.

Going back the example proposed in the question, following is a sample code (without using lambda):

```
print("========== Definition ==========")
def make_bold(fn):
    print("make_bold decorator")
    def wrapper():
        print("bold")
        return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"
    return wrapper

def make_italic(fn):
    print("make_italic decorator")
    def wrapper():
        print("italic")
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapper

@make_bold
@make_italic
def hello():
  return "hello world"

print("\n========== Execution ==========")
print(hello())
```

The output in this case:

```
========== Definition ==========
make_italic decorator
make_bold decorator

========== Execution ==========
bold
italic
<b><i>hello world</i></b>
```

Newly the order of execution is from top to bottom. We can apply the same to the original code (a little bit modified to print where are we):

```
print("========== Definition ==========")

def make_bold(fn):
    print("make_bold")
    return lambda: print("exec_bold") or "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"

def make_italic(fn):
    print("make_italic")
    return lambda: print("exec_italic") or "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"

@make_bold
@make_italic
def hello():
  return "hello world"

print("\n========== Execution ==========")
print(hello())
```

The output is:

```
========== Definition ==========
make_italic
make_bold

========== Execution ==========
exec_bold
exec_italic
<b><i>hello world</i></b>
```

I hope this sheds some light on the decorators order in Python and how it's handled.

Comment: I can see that when you run `hello()` the `print("make_bold")` and `print("make_italic")` didn't run again like they were in the Definition process, which means that in the Execution process what is being run is the return values(in this case are the lambda functions) of the decorators.