# How to monkey patch datetime.datetime.now()?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

test.py

```
@patch('I want to patch datetime.datetime.now here')
def test_function():
    import my_module
    my_module.some_function()
    ...
```

my_module.py

```
from datetime import datetime

def some_function():
    now = datetime.now()
```

By the way, I'm using pytest.

Comment: Patch it *where*?! What is the import you're trying to patch over and how is it written?

Answer (score 3):

I think [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) might be the module you're looking for.

Comment: I know and have used freezegun before, it is not what I need.

Answer (score -1):

You need to patch the specific import you want to replace, and provide a parameter for the mock; try something like:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import my_module

@patch('my_module.datetime')
def test_function(datetime):
    datetime.now.return_value = ...
    my_module.some_function()
    ...
    datetime.now.assert_called_once_with()
```

To only patch `now`, use:

```
@patch.object('my_module.datetime', 'now')
def test_function(now):
    now.return_value = ...
    my_module.some_function()
    ...
    now.assert_called_once_with()
```

Comment: There's a problem here. I don't want to patch the whole datetime class, just `datetime.now()`, cause I need other methods.

Comment: It says: `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'rsplit'`

Comment: @laike9m which line, the patch? Maybe I missed some quotes

Comment: @laike9m did that work? I'm out of the house so can't test, sorry.

Comment: @laike9m double-checking in [my own project](https://github.com/textbook/halliwell/blob/657c00b200a68cd0dbdd3e93e272ae739cd82e07/tests/parser/test_person.py#L63), the first argument should be an object, not a string.

Comment: No. I patched two other things, now it says `fixture 'mock_upvote_time' not found`, `mock_upvote_time` is another patched function which works before adding `@patch('utils.datetime', 'now')`

Comment: @laike9m you will need to put any fixtures *before* the injected mock. Patches appear in the parameter list *"inside out"*, also worth noting (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342149/decorator-execution-order). A [mcve] of your actual situation would have made this much easier; could you edit the question accordingly?

Comment: I'm sure the other two patches are correct. Tried all kinds of combinations still can't get it working.

Comment: @laike9m it is a waste of both of our time for me to debug what I *guess* you're doing. Please edit the question to give a useful example, with the specific error(s) you're seeing, or you might as well just delete it.

Comment: @laike9m see [here](https://github.com/textbook/halliwell/blob/493c7371724ff4457cb3a416cb0d732f0a8e8fc6/tests/test_bot.py#L53) for an example with both patch and fixture; patches should be *first*, sorry.

Comment: OK I found a similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481954/python-trying-to-mock-datetime-date-today-but-not-working, though it doesn't seem to apply to me cause I can't replace things in another module. Anyway, `mock` is unable to do patch this, according to that question and my experiments.