# Mocking two methods from the same class

Tags: python, mocking

I have the following code:

```
@istest
@patch.object(Chapter, 'get_author')
@patch.object(Chapter, 'get_page_count')
def test_book(self, mock_get_author, mock_get_page_count):
    book = Book() # Chapter is a field in book

    mock_get_author.return_value = 'Author name'
    mock_get_page_count.return_value = 43

    book.get_information() # calls get_author and then get_page_count
```

In my code, get_page_count, which is called after get_author, is returning 'Autor name' instead of the expected value of 43. How can I fix this? I've tried the following:

```
@patch('application.Chapter')
def test_book(self, chapter):
    mock_chapters = [chapter.Mock(), chapter.Mock()]
    mock_chapters[0].get_author.return_value = 'Author name'
    mock_chapters[1].get_page_count.return_value = 43
    chapter.side_effect = mock_chapters

    book.get_information()
```

But then I get an error:

```
TypeError: must be type, not MagicMock
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your decorator usage is not in the right order, that is why. You want, starting from the bottom, working up, patch for 'get_author', then 'get_page_count' based on how you are setting your arguments in your `test_book` method.

```
@istest
@patch.object(Chapter, 'get_page_count')
@patch.object(Chapter, 'get_author')
def test_book(self, mock_get_author, mock_get_page_count):
    book = Book() # Chapter is a field in book

    mock_get_author.return_value = 'Author name'
    mock_get_page_count.return_value = 43

    book.get_information() # calls get_author and then get_page_count
```

There is no better way to explain this other than referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342171/1832539) excellent answer to explain what exactly is happening when you use multiple decorators.