# Error: types.coroutine() expects a callable

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following class:

```
from tornado import gen

class VertexSync(Vertex):
    @wait_till_complete
    @gen.coroutine
    @classmethod
    def find_by_value(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        stream = yield super().find_by_value(*args, **kwargs)
        aggr = []
        while True:
            resp = yield stream.read()
            if resp is None:
                break
            aggr = aggr + resp
        return aggr
```

> TypeError: types.coroutine() expects a callable

Can you tell me what the problem is?

=> edit
Code calling this function

```
print(DemoVertex.find_by_value('longitude', 55.0))
```

Comment: `@classmethod` doesn't return a callable. Switch the decorators around, so that `gen.coroutine` is called first.

Comment: Please include the code calling this function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what does `@classmethod` return and how to make it a corutine?

Comment: @freeza it returns `<classmethod object at 0x...>`, and `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable`. You need to re-order your decorators.

Comment: @advance512 note that it doesn't matter in this case, as the error is thrown at class definition time.

Comment: Yep, I got that after reading your earlier comment. Also, if I'm not mistaken, what is actually returned is an iterable, not a callable. (Haven't touched Tornado for years, moved to greenlet land)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `classmethod` does... interesting things. Once the class definition has *finished* you have a nice callable method on the class, but *during the definition* you have a `classmethod object`, which isn't callable:

```
>>> a = classmethod(lambda self: None)
>>> a
<classmethod object at 0x10b46b390>
>>> callable(a)
False
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

The simplest fix is to re-order the decorators, so that rather than trying to turn a classmethod into a coroutine:

```
@gen.coroutine
@classmethod
def thing(...):
    ...
```

you are trying to turn a coroutine into a classmethod:

```
@classmethod
@gen.coroutine
def thing(...):
    ...
```

Note that the decorators are applied *"inside out"*, see e.g. [Decorator execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27342149/3001761)