# Order of decorator for abstract method

Tags: python, tornado

I have a base class which I have made abstract.

```
class X(metaclass=ABCMeta):

   @abstractmethod
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def cc(self):
      # do stuff
```

What should the order of the decorators go in? And does it matter?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37995862/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27342149/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of stacked function decorators usually does matter for correct interpretation (based on the flow of your program), and in this case it is stated explicitly in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> When `abstractmethod()` is applied in combination with other method descriptors, it should be applied as the innermost decorator...

So in your case, you should swap the order to make it the innermost decorator.

```
class X(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    @abstractmethod
    def cc(self):
       # do stuff
```