# Mock Patches Appearing in the Wrong Order?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a test module (`test.py`) which imports functions from another module (`keyboard.py`).

`keyboard.py`

```
def get_keys(keyList, timeStamped):
    return event.getKeys(keyList=keyList, timeStamped=timeStamped)

def wait_keys(keyList, timeStamped):
    return event.waitKeys(keyList=keyList, timeStamped=timeStamped)
```

`test.py`

```
@mock.patch('keyboard.wait_keys')
@mock.patch('keyboard.get_keys')
def test_2(self, mock_waitKeys, mock_getKeys):

    mock_waitKeys.return_value = [['wait_keys!', 0.1]]
    mock_getKeys.return_value = [['get_keys!',0.1]]

    run_blocks(trials,noise,win,expInfo, incorrect, tone1, tone2, experiment_details,allPoints,32,60)
```

I'm trying to put two mock return values in place but their effects are inversed.

When I call them in the interactive console while stopped at a breakpoint—or inspect the values when called normally—the two mocked functions return each other's fake return values. From the console:

```
get_keys()
Out[2]: [['wait_keys!', 0.1]]
wait_keys()
Out[3]: [['get_keys!', 0.1]]
```

Why are my mock patches appearing in the wrong order?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The order of your patches should be reversed, as they are applied bottom up. See this comment in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) on nested mock arguments:

> Note When you nest patch decorators the mocks are passed in to the
>   decorated function in the same order they applied (the normal python
>   order that decorators are applied). This means from the bottom up, so
>   in the example above the mock for module.ClassName1 is passed in
>   first.