# Python, How to add another decorator to filter the output of the existing multi decorators with property in python?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have 2 existing decorators to function in python, **@property** and **@safe_property**. Those decorators can't be changed, and they are part of the code that I have no access.

```
def safe_property(original_property):
    def wrap(self):
        try:
            return original_property(self)
        except AttributeError as e:
            pass
    return wrap

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    @safe_property
    def do_func(self):
        print("inside do_func!")
        return [2,3,4]
```

By calling the function:

```
a = MyClass()
print(a.do_func)
```

The output is good for me!:

```
inside do_func!
[2, 3, 4]
```

Now, another feature has come and I'm trying to filter out some of the return values of **do_func** according to an **(optional)** additional argument. That means that some user could continue work as usual and call:

```
print(a.do_func)
```

While others could call with a filter:

```
print(a.do_func(True))
```

In order to try this, I created another decorator called **my_decorator** such as:

```
def my_decorator(*args, **kwargs):

    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    def wrapper(*args):
        print(args)
        if args[1] == True:
            return
            # how do I return filter?
        else:
            return #without the filter?
    return wrapper


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @my_decorator
    @property
    @safe_property
    def do_func(self):
        print("inside do_func!")
        return [2,3,4]
```

The current output of this functionality is:

```
(<property object at 0x02AF0090>,)
{}
(<__main__.MyClass object at 0x00BCDBB0>, True)
None
```

How can I filter only the odd number ** for example,** of the return list from:
**do_func**?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is how you nest the decorators. `@property` should be the top-most decorator, if your other decorators handle functions. `property()` turns a function into something else (a property; which is a descriptor), so any decorators _above_ it need to handle properties instead of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying your decorator to the **output** of the `@property` decorator. That decorator produces a [`property()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), not a function. That's because decorators are applied *outward* from the function definition; see my [answer on decorator execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342149/decorator-execution-order/27342171#27342171); so `@safe_property` is applied first, then `@property`, then `@my_decorator`.

If you wanted to decorate the getter function, place your decorator right above the `def` statement, it'll be executed first, and whatever your decorator returns will be passed to the `safe_property()` decorator (which adds its own wrapper function):

```
@property
@safe_property
@my_decorator
def do_func(self):
    print("inside do_func!")
    return [2,3,4]
```

or, seeing as `@safe_property` also produces a wrapper function that's suitable as a getter function, you can place your decorator in between the `@safe_property` and `@property` lines to wrap the wrapper function returned the former:

```
@property
@my_decorator
@safe_property
def do_func(self):
    print("inside do_func!")
    return [2,3,4]
```

Either way, your decorator wrapper is passed the callable to decorate, and should return a replacement. Property getters only take `self`, your replacement would be called with `self` too, and no other arguments:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self):  # a replacement getter function, so only self is passed in
        result = func(self)  # call the original getter
        if self.some_flag:  # you can access the instance in the wrapper
            # return only odd values from the getter
            return [i for i in result if i % 2]
        else:
            # otherwise return the values unchanged
            return result
    return wrapper
```

To place `@my_decorator` at the top is to decorate a `property()` object, not a function, so you'd need to specifically handle being passed such an object (you can see how a `@property` decorator works in [an answer I wrote before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work/17330273#17330273)).

E.g. you could *extract* the getter from the `property().fget` attribute, and then return an appropriate replacement (which would be another `property()` object):

```
def my_decorator(prop):
    getter = prop.fget
    def wrapper(self):  # a replacement getter function, so only self is passed in
        result = getter(self)  # call the original getter, taken from the property
        if self.some_flag:  # you can access the instance in the wrapper
            # return only odd values from the getter
            return [i for i in result if i % 2]
        else:
            # otherwise return the values unchanged
            return result
    # return a new property object, with the wrapper as the getter function
    # and copying across all other property attributes
    return property(wrapper, prop.fset, prop.fdel, prop.doc)
```

Note that a property `getter` function will only ever be passed `self`, there are no other arguments for property getters possible.

However, handling a `property` object directly doesn't really have any advantages over placing your decorator one line lower, it only complicates matters by having to add the `prop.fget` reference and `property(...)` return value.