# Flask-Login How to check if a user has a certain attribute value

Tags: python, authentication, flask, web, flask-login

i am currently using flask-login for the Authentication of my website.
My Model is a simple User (with id, mail etc) which has an admin(boolean) attribute.
I dont need more than 2 Roles.

Is there any way to check after a route was called, if the current user has the value "True" at the admin attribute?

I tried solving this issue with trying out custom decorator, as well as accessing session['admin'] , but it did not work.

Comment: have you tried using `current_user` provided by flask-login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Agung Wiyono commented Flask-Login provides a `current_user` variable, see [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.current_user).

In your route you can do something like:

```
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route("/test")
@login_required
def test():

    if current_user.admin:
        print('user is admin')

    #  blah blah
```

If you don't want to use the `login_required` decorator:

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():

    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.admin:
        print('user is authenticated and is an admin')

    #  blah blah
```

If you want to use a decorator to check if the `current_user` admin value is `True`:

```
def admin_role_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method in EXEMPT_METHODS:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.admin:
            abort(403)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

This code is more or less the code of `@login_required`, except it checks the state of the `admin` attribute - see [source](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/flask_login/utils.py#L234).

And use as below. Note the [order of the decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342171/2800058) is important. `@login_required` is called first then `@admin_role_required` is called. Decorator `admin_role_required` assumes the `current_user` is already authenticated. If `admin_role_required` was called first then the `current_user` proxy would not have an attribute `admin` and you'd have an error.

```
@app.route("/test")
@admin_role_required
@login_required
def test():

    #  need to be logged in and admin be True to get here
    
    #  blah blah
```