# Limit access to views in Django based on account type

Tags: django

How to limit access to views in Django? My Account model is like this:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
      ...
      account_type    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I want to use a custom decorator to all my views based on account type but I don't know where to start.

Currently on my views, this is what I have done:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request, *args, **kwargs):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.account_type == 1:
            return redirect('admin_page')
        else:
            ....
```

But this one is very repetitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom decorator with [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/) method, like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test, login_required

user_limit = user_passes_test(lambda user: user.account_type != 1, login_url='admin_page')

def account_redirect(view_func):
    decorated_view_func = login_required(user_limit(view_func), login_url='/login/')
    return decorated_view_func

@account_redirect
def dashboard(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # rest of the code
```

Basically what I am doing is that if user's account type is 1, I am redirecting it to 'admin_page' url.

Also I found this [medium article](https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/custom-decorators-to-check-user-roles-and-permissions-in-django-ece6b8a98d9d) very useful for using `user_passes_test` method with dectorators.

Comment: Shouldn't `login_required` be above `account_redirection` here? Otherwise there may be an `AttributeError` if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Well order of the decorators in python are from bottom to top. So login required will execute before account redirection :) Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342149/decorator-execution-order

Comment: From what I understand `dashboard` is wrapped by `login_required` which is wrapped by `account_redirection()` meaning the first to execute would be the part of `account_redirection()`. The bottom up part means the result of the bottom ones is passed to the upper ones. So this would cause an `AttributeError` if user is not logged in.

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing that out.
I found out from the login_required method's github code, that there is a way to pass on a function in login_required decorator. Now I am using that to prevent un authorized access to user_limit method.