# Is there a way I can extend Django login_required decorator to check for a boolean field in my custom model?

Tags: python, django, decorator

I am working on a web application that has 5 different kinds of users, which are being differentiated by boolean fields in my custom user model.

```
is_estate_vendor = models.BooleanField(
        _('estate_vendor'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as an estate admin.'
        ),
    )
    is_estate_admin = models.BooleanField(
        _('estate_admin'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as an estate admin.'
        ),
    )
    is_estate_security = models.BooleanField(
        _('estate_security'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as estate security.'
        ),
    )
    is_estate_residence = models.BooleanField(
        _('estate_residence'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as estate residence.'
                    ),
    )
    is_estate_head_security = models.BooleanField(
        _('estate_head_security'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as estate head security.'
        ),
    )
    is_super_admin = models.BooleanField(
        _('super_admin'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as superadmin.'
        ),
    )
```

I'm trying to extend Django `login_decorator` to check for which user is logged-in base on which of that boolean fields is true and redirect any authenticated user to the login page if he/she tries to access the dashboard of another kind of user. I tried to create a custom decorator that checks for those fields:

```
def vendor_login_required(function):
   def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
     vendor=request.user.is_estate_vendor
     userAuth = request.user.isAuthenticated:  
     if not userAuth:
        message.success(request, "Please login")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
     elif userAuth and not vendor:
        message.error(request, "You are not authorized to be here, login as a vendor to 
                      continue")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
     else:
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

For some reason this is not working, I'll appreciate a way around this.

Comment: Rather than extend the `login_decorator` why not just make a separate decorator and then have it run after the login has been checked? [Decorator Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342149/decorator-execution-order)

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Yes thank you, That's exactly what I did. I had to chain my custom decorator to `login_required` for all views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usecase is more applicable to the decorator [@user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) where you just have to return either `True` or `False` whether the view must be continued or if must be redirected to the login page, no more need to manually perform the `HttpResponseRedirect` or the calling of the `view`.

> **`user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name='next')`**
>
> As a shortcut, you can use the convenient user_passes_test decorator which performs a redirect when the callable returns False:

It would look something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test

def is_estate_vendor(user):
    return user.is_estate_vendor

@login_required  # This will check if a user is currently logged-in, whether estate vendor, admin, security, etc.
@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_estate_vendor)  # This will check of the user has the correct boolean fields set to access this view
# @user_passes_test(is_estate_vendor)  # Use this if you need to use the function above to perform more complex checks
def my_view_for_estate_vendor(request):
    ...
```